# Build error for macOS in Swift Package for iOS platform

Tags: swift, swift-package-manager

I am trying to add support for Swift Package Manager to one of my frameworks. The framework is iOS specific (I make use of UIKit on it), so I added the `platforms` configuration to my Package.swift file which now looks like this:

```
import PackageDescription


let package = Package(
    name: "MyLibrary",
    platforms: [
        .iOS(.v11)
    ],
    products: [
        .library(
            name: "MyLibrary",
            targets: ["MyLibrary"]),
    ],
    targets: [
        .target(
            name: "MyLibrary",
            path: "Sources"),
        .testTarget(
            name: "MyLibraryTests",
            dependencies: ["MyLibrary"]),
    ]
)
```

Even though the package builds correctly on Xcode. When running `swift build` in the console I get the following error.

```
error: no such module 'UIKit'
```

Adding the `-v` flag to make the compilation more verbose I see that it is trying to build the package for macOS and that's why it fails.

Why is it building the framework for macOS if it is not listed in `platforms`? is this not the way to make an iOS specific swift package?

Comment: Possibly a caching issue. SPM caches artefacts, including manifests. When you invoke `swift package` on the command line you see various cache related options and commands in the output. You may try to clear the caches, and retry. Hope this helps.

Comment: I cleared up all caches and even created a brand new project. Sadly it did not work, still getting the same error.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?

Answer (score 3):

I've hit this myself, and the key is that the list of supported platforms you define in `platforms` doesn't exclude any platforms you don't list, it only sets a minimum for those that you do.

This isn't clear in the [docs for `SupportedPlatform`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift_packages/supportedplatform). However, in the [Creating a Standalone Swift Package with Xcode](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift_packages/creating_a_standalone_swift_package_with_xcode) page, there's a comment at the bottom that tackles the issue (my emphasis):

> Note how the package manifest below declares minimum deployment targets by passing them in as a value to the platforms parameter of the `Package` initializer. **However, passing minimum deployment targets to the initializer doesn’t restrict the package to the listed platforms.**

Instead, what you might be able to do is use conditional compilation blocks around your code. So instead of just

```swift
import UIKit

extension UIColor {
  // or whatever UIKit dependency you're using
}
```

you can wrap your code in a check so that it skips everything if you're building for macOS:

```swift
#if !os(macOS)
import UIKit

// your code
#endif
```

Or maybe even, to be a little cleverer about it, check for the existence of `UIKit` so that you're building based on a feature set, rather than a platform:

```swift
#if canImport(UIKit)
import UIKit

// your code
#endif
```